# Using a model to populate dynamic UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift

So far in my application, I am able to populate table rows using an array of models. For instance, I would have a Model defined as an `NSObject` and use that to initialize an array on load then use that array to populate data using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

This time though, I am using the model to create one new entity, specifically I am using the tableview as a form to create a new user, my model is defined like so:

```
class NewJob: NSObject {

    var titleId : Int
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var telNoHome : String
    var telNoWork :String
    var telNoMobile :String
    var email :String
    var street : String
    var propertyNumber : String
    var flatNumber : String
    var town : String
    var county : String
    var locality : String
    var postcode : String
    var countryLookupId : Int
    var workFolderId : String
    var customerAvailibility : String
    var selectedBreadcrumb : String
    var userId : String
    var financeOption : String
    var companyId : String
    var isInitialAppointmentDone : Bool

    // designated initializer for a New Job
    init(titleId : Int,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        telNoHome : String,
        telNoWork   :String,
        telNoMobile :String,
        email   :String,
        street: String,
        propertyNumber: String,
        flatNumber  :String,
        town    :String,
        county  :String,
        locality    :String,
        postcode    :String,
        countryLookupId :Int,
        workFolderId:   String,
        customerAvailibility:   String,
        selectedBreadcrumb: String,
        userId: String,
        financeOption:  String,
        companyId   :String,
        isInitialAppointmentDone    :Bool
        ) {
            self.titleId = titleId
            self.firstName = firstName
            self.lastName = lastName
            self.telNoHome = telNoHome
            self.telNoMobile = telNoMobile
            self.telNoWork = telNoWork
            self.email = email
            self.street = street
            self.propertyNumber = propertyNumber
            self.flatNumber = flatNumber
            self.town = town
            self.county = county
            self.locality = locality
            self.postcode = postcode
            self.countryLookupId = countryLookupId
            self.workFolderId = workFolderId
            self.customerAvailibility = customerAvailibility
            self.selectedBreadcrumb = selectedBreadcrumb
            self.userId = userId
            self.financeOption = financeOption
            self.companyId = companyId
            self.isInitialAppointmentDone = isInitialAppointmentDone   
     }
}
```

Now in my `UITableView` I am getting quite stuck, as I don't need an array of `NewJob`s, I just need the one `NewJob` object, yet I need to map that `NewJob` to each of the `UITableView`'s rows.

I did consider trying some sort of array wizardy, i.e create a new array from the properties of the first object in my new array, but that just gets confusing.

Here is how my `AddJobController` is setup at the moment:

```
class AddJobController: UITableViewController {

static let textViewCell = "addJobTextFieldCell"
static let dateCell = "addJobDateCell"

var newJob = [NewJob]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.newJob.append(NewJob(
        titleId : 1,
        firstName : "",
        lastName : "",
        telNoHome : "",
        telNoWork : "",
        telNoMobile : "",
        email : "",
        street : "",
        propertyNumber : "",
        flatNumber : "",
        town : "",
        county : "",
        locality : "",
        postcode : "",
        countryLookupId : 5,
        workFolderId : "",
        customerAvailibility : "",
        selectedBreadcrumb : "",
        userId : "",
        financeOption : "",
        companyId : "",
        isInitialAppointmentDone : true
        ))

    var jobObject = newJob[0]
```

You can see where I am stuck at `jobObject`, as I'm not sure this is the correct way of going about this?

Comment: Building a form isn't that simple. Maybe you should consider a ready-made solution such as https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms

Comment: that looks awesome, is there a swift version?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, but it shouldn't be difficult to use it in a Swift project.

Comment: to generate form, instead of dynamic cells, use static cells